# Postman: couldn't get any response

Tags: node.js, postman

I have a time consuming API route, and sometimes i need to run it locally.

I never have any problem when I'm on a fast connection, but when I' on some slower one the request goes on Timeout after a couple of minutes showing the following:

[image]

The thing is:

- backend is working properly (It ends after a while and I'm currently saving everything on a file to get my result)
- i turned off the SLL toggle
- there's no proxy
- last but not least, timeout is set to 0 which should be infinity.

any suggestion?

Comment: There are different types of timeout. Are you sure you set the request timeout? Maybe you're setting the connection timeout.

Comment: the option states: "Request timeout in ms (0 for infinity)

Comment: Fair enough. And what if you set the request timeout to a really high value? Say 90 minutes or something?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback

Comment: @Gimby I tried to do that but i realized the req timed out. I think Mykola set me on the right track, gonna test it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation, (thanks @Mykola Borysyuk), i can confirm the request send the  timeout event after 2 minutes.

[server timeout doc](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback)

It was enough to add the following line to my route:

`req.setTimeout(300000);`

[setTimeout doc](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback)